# Проблема с JQuery в расширении для Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vkontakte-api, google-chrome

При попытке создать расширение для Chrome с использованием API vk.com всё время появляется ошибка:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery111102449981936226011_1 is not defined

Пример кода:

**Манифест:**

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "atata",
  "description": "ururu",
  "version": "1",

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://vk.com/*"],
      "js": [ "jq.js","vk_inject.js" ]
    }
  ]

  
}
```

**vk_inject.js**

```js
var btn = document.createElement (('v' == '\v') ? '<input name="myName">' : 'input'); btn.name = 'myName';
btn.type = 'button'; 
btn.id = 'myUniqueID';
btn.value = 'ок';
document.getElementById ('side_bar_inner').appendChild (btn); //добавил кнопку

btn.onclick = function(){

$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate',
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(msg){
     console.log(msg);


    }});
}
```

(ну и jq.js - файл с JQuery)

При этом если запустить данный код в виде обычного скрипта, то всё отлично работает. В чём же заключается проблема?

> **UPDATE** - проблема решается добавлением в манифест "permissions": ["https://api.vk.com/*"] и изменением в ajax-запросе `dataType:"json"`

Comment: jquery расположил в папку с расширением?

Comment: Не по теме, но раз уж вам, судя по сниппету кода, от jQuery нужны лишь AJAX-запросы, то почему бы не перейти на [Fetch API](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch), который уже давно [прекрасно поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) Хромом?